# how to specify which class to select with selenium (in python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to use the selenium module for python 3 to get some information from a website, that information is located in a class with the name "table_dark_green".
Now the problem is that there are multiple elements on this site with the class name "table_dark_green", and selenium only stores the last element with that class name. Is there a way to specify which one i would like to use?

Comment: if you ll use xpath then you can specify number of class in square brackets like '//div[@class="table_dark_green"][2]'

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_elements` then specify the element:

```
# this returns a list of elements
table_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("table_dark_green")
print(len(table_elements)) # print to see how meny elements are in he list
# you can specify the element in the list[0] or [1] ... [99]
print(table_elements[0].text)
```

Hope this helps you!